# Weird time out after 10 minutes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a web application that has a function that takes a while to run, nearly half an hour.

But after 10 minutes (and it's always 10 minutes) the page goes blank, and there is no error message or anything.

I tried running the same page from the web server through IIS and it works OK. Is only when I run it outside the server that this happens...

Anyone know why this could be hapenning?

Thanks

Comment: Which browsers have you tested with, and what results did you see on the different browsers?

Comment: How do you run a web application "outside the server"?

Comment: @p.campbell I tried IE and FF. FF returns a blank page. IE returns a standard error message

Comment: Can we see the code of your function?

Comment: Do you just have an aspx page doing processing with the timeout set really high, or do you do something like Ajax callbacks to check on the status of processing (which is very preferable to just having the aspx page run for a long time).

Comment: I think he means when he runs it from his browser, instead of running it from a browser on the sever - though I might be wrong

Comment: Which version of IIS you have on local PC and which one is on the remote server?

Comment: Web servers are not the place for extremely long running calculations. If calculations take this long, they should be hosted in a process separate from the web server.

Comment: @spender when I mean outside the server I mean I access it by a browser outside the server where the application lives

Comment: @spender: I think he means "outside local environment".

Comment: @user441365: Even while browsing, it is using remote server.

Comment: @Eric J. is an aspx page doing all the processing

Comment: @RPK the server runs IIS 6. I'm testing it with IE and FF on my machine

Comment: @spender how do I host a calculation hosted in a process separate from the web server?

Comment: @user441365 : create a WPF service with which the web-server can interact.

Answer (score 2):

Having a long running process inside of a web app that holds up the response of an HTTP request is not the best scenario. Most web browsers assume something is wrong with a web server if it does not respond within a 'reasonable' amount of time.

Your best solution is to que off an async thread to do your work and return a page to the user. This is by no means an easy solution, as it brings forward some issues that you would not normally have to worry about such as error handling and IIS killing the worker process due to inactivity in the request pipeline. However, there is a lot of information out there on running background processes in ASP.Net.

Some quick results I found by googling:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1244439/2282626.aspx#2282626

http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2008/08/04/Creating-a-Background-Thread-to-Log-IP-Information.aspx

http://flimflan.com/blog/SafelyRunningBackgroundThreadsInASPNET20.aspx

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4272/net-threading-part-ii/6/

Comment: can you give me an example of how to do this please?

Comment: thanks @Jay I'll try these. Still, it doesn't explain why the script does work when running through IIS...

Answer (score 0):

Could be the browser is giving up/timing out or the OS cutting the connection?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to execute your page using a built in development server for Visual Studio,
you can try to modify

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe.config
```

or similar by adding the following under configuration node:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="1048576"  executionTimeout="3600"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on some legacy projects that hard to refactor got the same problem, it need to run 30 mins since we moved servers to VM, no body willing to fix the VM issue so I was asked to find a solution and I found that using **Reponse.Flush** do solve this problem.

The timeout was from browsers as they can't get any response data from web servers for quite a while, so browser quit for waiting, but if you add **Response.Flush** even at the very beginning it flushed the http headers to client side, and it makes the Browser do know server is alive so browser will keep waiting for more data coming.

Yes I know this is not a good practice and we should do something like Jay mentioned, but if you got someone standing behind keep pushing you asking for quickly solve it then try this first.